# Reverse Proxy using Go to Cloud Run Instance

Tags: go, google-cloud-run

I feel like I'm close to having this working but so far I"m running into an issue building a small reverse proxy in Go to a GCP Cloud Run instance. The request 'goes through' but the response from the request is the default GCP Cloud Run 404. It appears when making the request back to Cloud Run the Host header is being ignored and therefore the request is not being routed correction.

What might I be missing here?

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
)

const apiUrl = "MY_CLOUD_RUN.a.run.app"

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", proxy)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil))
}

func proxy(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    // gets past CORS checks
    if req.Method == http.MethodOptions {
        headers := res.Header()
        headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        headers.Add("Vary", "Origin")
        headers.Add("Vary", "Access-Control-Request-Method")
        headers.Add("Vary", "Access-Control-Request-Headers")
        headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
        headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE")
        res.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        return
    }

    p := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(&url.URL{
        Scheme: "http",
        Host:   apiUrl,
    })
    p.Director = func(req *http.Request) {
        req.Header.Add("X-Forwarded-Host", req.Host)
        req.Header.Add("X-Origin-Host", apiUrl)
        req.Header.Add("Host", apiUrl)
        req.Header.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        req.URL.Scheme = "https"
        req.URL.Host = apiUrl
    }
    p.ModifyResponse = func(res *http.Response) error {
        res.Header.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE")
        res.Header.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        res.Header.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        res.Header.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
        return nil
    }

    p.ServeHTTP(res, req)
}
```

Comment: I was finally able to get this to work after all. Not the exact code above but a variation of. I need to do some additional testing and cleanup before posting a follow up answer with the final  code that works should anyone else need an example.

Comment: Hi @djneely, could post it as answer so it would help the community. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit more elaborate than the original initial write-up but what we wound up with was as follows.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    "google.golang.org/api/idtoken"
)

var port = ":8080"
var backend = "[CLOUD_RUN_INSTANCE_TO_PROXY].a.run.app"

func main() {
    logger := log.New(os.Stdout, "proxy: ", log.LstdFlags)
    logger.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Proxy server is starting for: %s on port: %s", backend, port))

    router := http.NewServeMux()
    router.Handle("/", proxyHandler())

    server := &http.Server{
        Addr:         port,
        Handler:      logging(logger)(router),
        ErrorLog:     logger,
        ReadTimeout:  30 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: 30 * time.Second,
        IdleTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
    }

    done := make(chan bool)
    quit := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(quit, os.Interrupt)

    go func() {
        <-quit
        logger.Println("Proxy server is shutting down...")

        ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 30*time.Second)
        defer cancel()

        server.SetKeepAlivesEnabled(false)
        if err := server.Shutdown(ctx); err != nil {
            logger.Fatalf("Could not gracefully shutdown the server: %v\n", err)
        }
        close(done)
    }()

    if err := server.ListenAndServe(); err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
        logger.Fatalf("Could not listen on %s: %v\n", port, err)
    }

    <-done
    logger.Println("Server stopped")
}

func proxyHandler() http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.Method == http.MethodOptions {
            headers := w.Header()
            headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
            headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE")
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
            return
        }

        path := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s%s", backend, r.RequestURI)
        at, _ := idTokenTokenSource(path)

        p := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(&url.URL{
            Scheme: "https",
            Host:   backend,
        })
        p.Director = func(r *http.Request) {
            if at != nil {
                at.SetAuthHeader(r)
            }
        }
        p.ModifyResponse = func(res *http.Response) error {
            res.Header.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE")
            res.Header.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
            res.Header.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            res.Header.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
            return nil
        }

        r.URL.Scheme = "https"
        r.URL.Host = backend
        r.Header.Set("X-Forwarded-Host", r.Header.Get("Host"))
        r.Host = backend

        if at != nil {
            at.SetAuthHeader(r)
        }

        p.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func logging(l *log.Logger) func(http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            defer func() {
                requestId := r.Header.Get("X-Request-Id")
                if requestId == "" {
                    requestId = fmt.Sprintf("%d", time.Now().UnixNano())
                }
                w.Header().Set("X-Request-Id", requestId)
                l.Println(requestId, r.Method, r.URL.Path, r.RemoteAddr, r.UserAgent())
            }()

            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        })
    }
}

func idTokenTokenSource(audience string) (*oauth2.Token, error) {
    ts, err := idtoken.NewTokenSource(context.Background(), audience)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    t, err := ts.Token()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return t, nil
}
```

A good chunk of some of the graceful shutdown, http setup, and logging came from: https://gist.github.com/enricofoltran/10b4a980cd07cb02836f70a4ab3e72d7

Comment: Grateful for this  I have Grafana running in cloud run and spent 2 days fiddling with the proxy settings (all the solutions I found are for nginx) this is a lifesaver

Comment: @djneely did you figure out what specifically was causing the 404? I have the same problem and I set the site public so it's not due to a lack of id token or something like that

Comment: @Philio it it has been a while since I worked on this but I believe it was a combo of the id token and the host settings.

Comment: @djneely turned out to just be setting the host header, not sure why they have this weird restriction on Cloud Run. Thanks for the useful post.