# "Host header is specified and is not an IP address or localhost" message when using chromedp headless-shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, google-cloud-run, chromedp

I'm trying to deploy [chromedp/headless-shell](https://hub.docker.com/r/chromedp/headless-shell/) to Cloud Run.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM chromedp/headless-shell
ENTRYPOINT [ "/headless-shell/headless-shell", "--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0", "--remote-debugging-port=9222", "--disable-gpu", "--headless", "--no-sandbox" ]
```

The command I used to deploy to Cloud Run is

```sh
gcloud run deploy chromedp-headless-shell --source . --port 9222
```

#### Problem

When I go to this path `/json/list`, I expect to see something like this

```json
    [{
       "description": "",
       "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "/devtools/inspector.html?ws=localhost:9222/devtools/page/B06F36A73E5F33A515E87C6AE4E2284E",
       "id": "B06F36A73E5F33A515E87C6AE4E2284E",
       "title": "about:blank",
       "type": "page",
       "url": "about:blank",
       "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://localhost:9222/devtools/page/B06F36A73E5F33A515E87C6AE4E2284E"
    }]
```

but instead, I get this error:

> Host header is specified and is not an IP address or localhost.

Is there something wrong with my configuration or is Cloud Run not the ideal choice for deploying this?

Answer (score 1):

This specific issue is not unique to Cloud Run. It originates from an existing change in the Chrome DevTools Protocol which generates this error when accessing it remotely. It [could be attributed](https://groups.google.com/g/chrome-debugging-protocol/c/A6Zlr5IjQsg) to security measures against some types of attacks. You can see the related Chromium pull request [here](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/952522).

I deployed a `chromedp/headless-shell` container to Cloud Run using your configuration and also received the same error. Now, there is [this](https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp/issues/505#issuecomment-549188061) useful comment in a GitHub issue showing a workaround for this problem, by passing a `HOST:localhost` header. While this does work when I tested it locally, it does not work on Cloud Run (returns a 404 error). This 404 error [could be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70207857/r) due to how Cloud Run also utilizes the HOST header to [route requests](https://siipo.la/blog/fixing-the-host-header-when-running-a-reverse-proxy-on-google-cloud-run) to the correct service.

Unfortunately this answer is not a solution, but it sheds some light on what you are seeing and why. I would go for using a different service from GCP, such a GCE that are pure virtual machines and less managed.

Comment: I had tried on GCE before and was successful at it, but I want to auto-scale the instances depending on the traffic, that's why I wanted it to run on cloud run.

Comment: Implementing auto scaling can be done on GCE by creating a [managed instance group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups#autoscaling). The group would add or remove instances depending on factors such as CPU usage. To connect to them from the internet, you could use a [load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/adding-an-instance-group-to-a-load-balancer).